# Create a ProjectionOperation with Difference with spring mongodb

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

I have an projection, whitch i have to translate to java and i get not the correct result, like in the mongo db executer with javascript.

```
{
        $project: {"userId": 1, "followingAndNotFollowingBack": {
            $setDifference: ["$following", "$follower"]}}
}
```

until now i have in Java the following:

```
private static final ProjectionOperation PROJECTION_OPERATION = Aggregation.project(UserRelationships.FIELD_USER_ID)
            .and(SetOperators.SetDifference.arrayAsSet(UserRelationships.FIELD_FOLLOWING_USER_IDS)
                    .differenceTo(UserRelationships.FIELD_FOLLOWER_USER_IDS))
            .as(FOLLOWING_AND_NOT_FOLLOWED_BACK);
```

but i get everytime an `null`

did anybody see the problem?

#### thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Please try the below. I have used `differenceToArray`.

```
private static final ProjectionOperation PROJECTION_OPERATION = Aggregation.project(UserRelationships.FIELD_USER_ID)
            .and(UserRelationships.FIELD_FOLLOWING_USER_IDS)
                    .differenceToArray(UserRelationships.FIELD_FOLLOWER_USER_IDS)
            .as(FOLLOWING_AND_NOT_FOLLOWED_BACK);
```

**Another Example:-**

```
db.experiments.aggregate(
   [
     { $project: { A: 1, B: 1, inBOnly: { $setDifference: [ "$B", "$A" ] }, _id: 0 } }
   ]
)
```

**Code:-**

```
Aggregation aggregate = Aggregation.newAggregation(
            Aggregation.project("A", "B").and("B").differenceToArray("A").as("inBOnly").andExclude("_id"));
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the help, but the problem was, that I had different mongodbs in test and in life
so the differencetoarray with null was null in one version, and in the other it gave me the correct answer, so I had to add the info to give all back, if I union with null array.